# Transient "Access to OData is disabled" weirdness

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I am porting an application from Google Mail to Office365 Outlook as my employer has moved their enterprise email solution.

The application is a simple idea, essentially an RSS feed is generated for each ***category*** of an email inbox and each message with that category becomes a news item.

I am using the Microsoft Graph API.  It is configured as an Azure Active Directory App registration.  It uses "Application permissions" to access a shared mailbox.  It has the following application API permissions - fully granted:

```
Mail.Read - to read email
MailboxSettings.Read - to list categories
User.Read.All - just because
```

So initially the application appears to be working fine, I can list categories and access the messages in the inbox mail folder.

My Azure admin has limited the permissions to a couple of specific email accounts à la [Scoping application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access)

My Azure admin doesn't think there are any other policies that he can see that would prevent it from working.

**BUT** if I archive or delete a message via the Office365 Outlook web interface - I start to get "**Access to OData is disabled**" errors when the application attempts to list categories (or any other access).

The limitation would seem to be limited to a specific email account - as other email accounts working with the same App registration (same client id and permissions) continue to work.

It would also appear that after a few hours (I think about 2 hours) - the error messages stop and everything works again.

Help!  Is this related to accessing the mailbox from multiple "clients" simultaneously?

---

**Update**

Example error:

```
{
   "error": {
     "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
     "message": "Access to OData is disabled.",
     "innerError": {
       "request-id": "03892cab-e0d2-4149-8971-76c02081ea06",
       "date": "2019-07-19T07:30:06"
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error message in the http response you get. We can look at the request-id you provide behind the scenes to see what is going on...

Comment: @JeremyThakeMSFT Please see example error in the update above.  Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @JeremyThakeMSFT any progress?  Is there a ticket I could follow or something? Many thanks.

Comment: we are actively looking into this and will get progress on here

Comment: Hi @MarkMcLaren, our primary investigations show that the request-id is incorrect. Can you repro the issue again and share the error payload/request-id that you see in the response?

Comment: I will upload a new request-id.  This is the European Azure does that make a difference?

Comment: 926dd509-e455-412a-a7ec-009c18bf5e44